# Easy to use DAW

Tags: daw

I am currently using open-source DAW program LMMS but it is very difficult to me. Is there any easier program for a beginner? Or which one do you most recommend except Logic Pro because i do not have any Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FL Studio is quite simple to use. It's very powerful, too.
You can buy the basic version for only 99$.